# The which() function in R is not working for some reason

Tags: r, function

I am getting an 'integer(0)' result for the following query in one instance of my code, but it works fine otherwise:

data.dat:

> xx, linear, squared, gaussian, rando, fruit, color, type, xxx, yyy
>
> 1, 1,  1,  1,   1.1, apple, blue, gold, 1, 1
>
> 2, 3,  4,  1,   2.5, apple, red, gold, 2, 1
>
> 3, 2,  9,  2,   4.4, orange, blue, silver, 1, 1
>
> 4, 4,  16,  3,  5.9, orange, blue, gold, 1, 1
>
> 5, 5,  25,  5,  5.5, peach, blue, gold, 1, 1
>
> 6, 6,  32,  12, 6.9, peach, blue, gold, 1, 2
>
> 7, 7,  48,  24, 7.2, apple, blue, silver, 1, 1
>
> 8, 9,  66,  30, 7.4, apple, blue, gold, 1, 2
>
> 9, 8,  84,  31, 7.6, pear, red, gold, 1, 1
>
> 10,10, 102, 30, 1.5, orange, red, gold, 1, 1

```
data2 <- read.csv(file="data.dat",head=TRUE,sep=",");
which(data2$color=="red" , arr.ind=TRUE)
```

This isn't working either:

```
which(as.character(data2$color)=="red" , arr.ind=TRUE)
```

I feel like I'm losing my mind, I've used this function hundreds of times with no issue...

Comment: Looks like you have colors " red" and " blue" rather than "red" and "blue"

Comment: Could have used `grep("red", data2$color)`. BTW, Using `arr.ind=TRUE` with a vector argument makes no sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extra whitespace in your entries. Try:

```
which(trimws(data2$color) == "red")
```

Comment: I'm the worst. Thank you for your help. I'ts been a long night.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot!